# jQuery obscurity

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is kind of funky. But take a look at the code snippet below :

```
$('.classname').bind('click', somefunction);

function somefunction() {
  console.log($(this)); // **displays[<div>,context<div>]**
}
```

And if I tweak the above to:

```
$('.classname').bind('click', function(){ somefunction(); });

function somefunction(){
  console.log($(this)); // **displays [Window]**
}
```

I am not quite sure why 'this' assumes two different values depending on how the function is being called back. The thing is, I do need this to be ,context and the function to be called like

```
function(event){ somefunction(event); }
```

because I need the event. But not quite sure what's up here.

Any leads, people?

Comment: This might help: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am not quite sure why 'this' assumes two different values depending on how the function is being called..."*

That's exactly how `this` works in JavaScript. Its value is based on *how* the function was called.

---

You can manually set it to the value you want using `.call` or `.apply`.

```
$('.classname').bind('click', function(event){ 
                                  somefunction.call(this, event); 
                              });
```

Now there's no need to modify `somefunction`. By invoking it with `.call()`, you're manually setting the `this` value to whatever you pass as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the receiver of the function.

When you execute `obj.someFunction()`, it is `obj` inside the execution.

But if you take the function and execute it without an explicit receiver (and it wasn't bound) it's the global scope, that is `window` :

```
function someFunction(){
    console.log(this);
}
var f = obj.someFunction;
f(); // log the window
```

Note that you may *bind* the function, using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
 var f = obj.someFunction.bind(obj);
 f(); // log the obj
```

But the usual solution is to use a closure, that is another function, to embed the this wyou want :

```
var f = function(){obj.someFunction()};
f(); // log the obj
```

That's why you often see this construct in jquery callbacks :

```
$(someselector).click(function(event){
    $(this).someFunction(event)
 }); // this is $(this) and the event is received
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is being passed in the first example as well

```
$('.classname').bind('click', somefunction);

function somefunction(e) {
  // e is the event here as well..
  console.log($(this)); // **displays[<div>,context<div>]**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.classname').bind('click',somefunction);
```

Means "run `somefunction()` on `$('.classname')`" `$('.classname')` will be passed as `this`.

```
$('.classname').bind('click',function(){somefunction();});
```

Means "run this anonymous function on `$('.classname')`" In your anonymous function `$('.classname')` is `this`, but when you call `somefunction()` inside the anonymous function, `this` doesn't get passed to it. You could fix that with.

```
$('.classname').bind('click', function(){ somefunction(this); });

function somefunction(x){
  console.log($(x));
}
```